# Using Edge Chromium for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-email, edge

We have a SharePoint 2019 on premise system. We've encountered an issue where emails always download instead of opening automatically in Outlook when using Edge Chromium  All other document types in system (word, Excel and TXT) open in the default client application. When I try an another browser like Firefox emails do open in Outlook automatically. This seems to suggest there is nothing with configuration or settings of our SharePoint system but a problem with Edge Chromium itself. The organization I work for seems keen to use Edge Chromium as its default browser. I was wondering if there is a way to get around the problem. Nothing I have tried within Edge Chromium settings stops the downloading of emails. So I'm beginning to wonder if we need to dump it for another browser. Any advise/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file extension do the emails use?  *.eml or *.msg

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue in Chrome and Edge, in addition, this works on IE.

[image]

There is no OOB way to prevent Chrome and Edge downloading email files first.

As a workaround, after downloading the file, we could set "**always open files of this type**" option to automatically Open Downloads in outlook client as shown below:

[image]

[image]

If this is not feasible for you, we suggest you switch to another browser that supports this feature.